# Randomly select picture url's stored within objects that are stored within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, random, modal-dialog

I am writing a code that displays 6 random pictures, and when one of those pictures is click it opens a modal of that picture. In total I have 48 thumbnails and 48 of the same images except larger high resolution.

I want to be able to display 6 random thumbnails in a row. Then I want to be able to click any one of those thumbnails and have a fullscreen modal open up the the respective image. Then I want to have arrows that will let me move through every picture, left or right, in the array.

So far it's only displaying the src image (avengers_5.jpg), and not the random pics. I tried to access each of the thumbnails with the picArray.thumbnail.length line, but it's a no-go.

Please note, I used id's and need to change it to classes so it works on all 6 pictures. I'm in the process of doing that and making the array of objects. Here is my html (abridged), my js (abridged) and my css (abridged):

```
        let picArray = [
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_1.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_1.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_2.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_2.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_3.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_3.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_4.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_4.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_5.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_5.jpg"},
             {thumbnail: "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_6.jpg", image: 
             "https://rcabrerapics.s3.us-east- 
             2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_6.jpg"}]
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="root">
        </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="pics">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <div class="photosTitle"><h3>Photos</h3></div>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <img id="myImg" src="https://rcabrerapics.s3.us- 
                    east-2.amazonaws.com/assets/avengers_large_5.jpg" 
                    width="99" height="99" class="avengerPic">
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                      <div id="caption"></div>
                    </div>
```

```
let moviePics = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.avengerPic').forEach(function(e) {
    const randomPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * picArray.thumbnail.length));
    e.src = picArray[randomPic];
  });
}

moviePics();

let modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

let img = document.getElementById("myImg");
let modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
let captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  vertical-
align: middle;
  margin: 5px 15px;
}

.pics img {
  padding: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed; /* doesn't move */
  z-index: 1; /* on top */
  padding-top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  /* background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.75); */
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  /* position: fixed; */
  display: block;
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 1000;
  max-height: 520;
}

.caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  font-size: 40px;
  /* font-weight: bold; */
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: `picArray.thumbnail.length` will throw a type error (`picArray.thumbnail is undefined`)

Comment: Yes you are correct. Can you show me how to access each thumbnail so I can display 6 random thumbnails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use this line in `movePics` function

```
const randomPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * picArray.length));
e.src = picArray[randomPic].image // or .thumbnail to get thumbnail url
```

It will give you a random image but not unique.

In your HTML you are using img element with id `myImg` and it is in `tr` so it means you will be having multiple images and all images have same id and when you select the element using the id you will get the last element always, so please use class instead of the id.

Comment: You're right!! The random thumbnail now works!! Thank you!! Now I'll work on using the class in the html.